# `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whenever

I am trying to execute rake task using crontab and getting following error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:22
```

Can anyone help me with this?

I have ruby & Bundler installed at usr/local/bin
error shows for usr/bin

Comment: no its different scene bcoz it is deployed on production server

Comment: have you run ```bundle install``` on your production server ?

Comment: yes i did then i got new error :( `materialize': Could not find rake-10.3.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install 'bundler' Gem. Do

```
gem install bundler
```

and then run

```
bundle install
```

To run rake commands, use **bundle exec**

```
bundle exec rake command
```

Comment: i did still not working...it is already installed to /usr/local/bin

Comment: yes bundle installed but getting new error after that`materialize': Could not find rake-10.3.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Comment: @Riteshkatare Use 'bundle exec' with the rake command

Comment: i am running this crontab 0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /opt && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake ritesh:schedule_jobs --silent >> log/cron.log 2>> log/reports_error.log'

Comment: install rake ```gem install rake```